# bash substring and positional parameters

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have to compile some mysql c api code and tired of writing all this in command line:

```
gcc main.c -o main `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

I wrote a shell script in bash and pass positional parameter in bash:

`gcc $1 -o ${"$1":0:2} 'mysql_config --cflags --libs'` but this doesn't work.  I get error message:  `./compile: line 2: ${"$1":0:-2}: bad substitution`.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

The only way I got this to work is by assigning a new variable:

```
filename=$1;
gcc $filename -o ${filename:0:-2} `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

Is this the only way to do it or is there a way to fix what I am doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: Time to start learning about `make`... Or any other build-management tool...

Comment: @twalberg I thought `make` would only be appropriate for larger programs.  This is just a small test program.  thanks.

Comment: While it's true that it provides the most benefit for large complicated builds, it works perfectly fine for tiny single-source builds too...

Comment: @twalberg would you might showing me how it works in this case?

Comment: Posted an answer below to maintain formatting. Note the spacing at the beginning of the `gcc` line *must* be a single tab character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
${1:0:2}
```

You don't need another reference to `$1` inside the brackets since everything in it will be interpreted as the name of the variable, as in the case of `${filename:0:-2}`.

Comment: +1 Some explanation for the curious: `1` *is* the name of the parameter. However, the positional parameters aren't *variables* (i.e., parameters with valid identifiers as names), so you can't assign to it using variable assignment; `1=somestring` doesn't work. To set the value of a positional parameter, you need to use the `set` command.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the comments under the question, here's an example `makefile` for this situation:

```
MSQL_FLAGS := $(shell mysql_config --cflags)
MSQL_LIBS  := $(shell mysql_config --libs)

main : main.c
        gcc $(MSQL_FLAGS) -o $@ $< $(MSQL_LIBS)
```